# Select image shows black screen after selected and then times out

Tags: java, android, gallery, android-gallery

I have been trying to select an image from the gallery and then set an imageview on Android by using the following code, but when I select an image, it goes back to the "select an image screen" (i.e. the first screen that comes up after the intent starts) and after about 3 seconds, the screen turns black.  What's odd is that no errors are called, and about 1 in every 10 attempts, it actually works.  I am running 5.0.1 Lollipop on a Nexus 6, and I have figured out that onActivityResult is not being called whenever the screen goes black.  Thanks for any help,

Jacob

Here is my code:

```
public static int GAN = 1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_funky);
    Button a = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    ImageView b = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView5);

    a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(intent, GAN);
            System.out.println("hello world");


        }
    });


}


@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        System.out.println("hello world");



        if (requestCode == GAN && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Facing same issue right now, did u find any solution?

Comment: @AliAnsari So in my case, I found that it only worked on the first time pressed, so I adapted my app so that the user can only select his/her profile picture once.  That being said, I never found a good solution.